Multi thread Automation scripts Selenium C# (Threads - 8). After sometime the CPU went to 100% utilization as the Edge browser is not getting closed
Selenium  - C#
I triggered a multi-thread Automation scripts(200 scripts) (Threads - 8).
After some time the CPU went to 100% utilization as the MsEdge browser is not closing and it eats up all the memory
I do have Browser.Dispose() on every scenario but seems like nothing works
Error logs:

Unable to connect to the remote server
Error Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:
[ERROR] Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. -> Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:

tried Browser.Dispose() in afterscenario completion but nothing works.

Do you have code sample on how you initialize your driver instance ?

Post your code. We can't guess what you mean by "multithreaded" - I say that as someone that has to download data from 40 sites every day. Do you use multiple tabs in the sabe browser? Multiple windows? Multiple services (drivers)? It's not enough to close the browser, you have to close the WebDriver service that connects to it as well.

What you ask is essentially parallel test execution. If you search any article on parallel execution with Selenium you'll see that multiple drivers are used. You need to dispose those drivers as well, not just the browsers.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

finally
{
if (Framework.Browser != null)
{
try
{
Framework.Browser.Dispose();
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }

I dont think Browser,dispose() is working.

you don't need to use dispose.  Just use driver.quit().   Browsers are resource hogs.  When you have many threads/browsers going it's going to gobble up resources until you end up with a lot of timing issues.  One of those issues will be a timeout reached when trying to launch a new session.  You should also try to use a sleep after quitting one driver and starting the next  (the driver won't know how long the browser takes to cleanup after it shuts down)...  with multiple threaded scenarios that'll require some coordination to know when one browser is closing and another is opening.

the sleep is to insure that the file the browser drops to communicate the port/sessionid is cleaned up properly. (and other temp files/folders used during the session)

The main source of the error (Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost) is that when multiple Edge automation script driver instances are opened, it assigns the same port number to some instances, and which causes this problem. Therefore, you can try to assign a unique port number to each automation script driver instance.
Also, make sure to use the following calling driver methods:
driver.Close(); driver.Quit();driver.Dispose();

Alternatively, you can also try to use this EdgeOptions:
options.AddArgument("--disable-features=SharedBitmapToSharedImage");

